# Why does the while loop in that bash script stop after the first line

Tags: bash, while-loop, stdin

I was stepping through a list of files with a bash script.

But: it always stopped after the first loop although the list in "$tempdat" was 10 lines long.

```
while IFS= read -r zeile; do
 # Zielsteuerung
 quelle=$(awk -F\/ '{print $2}')
 if [[ "$quelle" == "foo" ]]; then
   do that
 else
   do s.th. else
 fi
 rsync somefiles
done < "$tempdat"
```

After some searching I found the error, the awk was not correct

```
quelle=$(echo "$zeile"|awk -F\/ '{print $2}')
```

But: why did that mistake prevent the loop from finishing? Maybe someone with more bash insight could be so nice to enlighten me. :-)

Comment: Your script will be terminated with exit code 1 as soon as the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` is consuming all of the data intended for the `read` in the condition of the loop.  Instead of using `awk` to try to parse the line, it seems like you intend to do:

```
while IFS=/ read -r a quelle b; do
```

and read the second column of the file into the variable `quelle`.

You can also write:

```
quelle=$(echo "$zeile" | awk -F\/ '{print $2}')
```

but it is generally best practice to let `read` split the fields for you.